# TF_OLD_DATA on Gazebo Simulation

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to simulate a turtlebot3 with Gazebo on Ubuntu16.04. My purpose is to test my launch files to see what happens without actually using the physical bot, as the bot is usually being used by others. In the command line I launch `roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch` to bring up rviz, then `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch` to start the Gazebo simulation. The problem I am having arises when I try to run `roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation move_base.launch`  -  I am greeted with a slew of

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_footprint at time 54.367 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.17/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

errors. I have already tried the suggestion of adding `<param name ="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>` before the node instantiation in the launch files. Any suggestions on how to combat this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I would love to be able to use Gazebo simulation to expedite testing. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296589/tf_old_data-on-gazebo-simulation/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

You don't need to launch fake node before launch gazebo packages.
Fake node provides related topics to simulate in Rviz. Launch files in turtlebot3_gazebo packages include spawn models to load robots.

Please follow attached Wiki to launch gazebo

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#ros-packages-for-gazebo

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2